# CSS add "vertical" dots at the end of a string

Tags: css, overflow

I would like to add 3 dots at the end of a string that can't fit in the height it's parent has, I have tried using ellipsis but it just works when the width is the fixed part and not the height. and when there are not line breaks, line breaks are an important part of this problem and they cannot be removed :(.

```css
#somediv{
  min-width: 100%; /*It's important to keep the width as 100%*/
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
```

```html
<div id="somediv">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam amet autem
  <br>
  consectetur corporis eaque laboriosam praesentium temporibus? Accusamus         <br>
  consequatur deserunt, dolorum eaque facere inventore labore mollitia possimus,   <br>
  quia quo, veniam.
  <br>
  br tags are some important part of the example  
  <br>
  As you can see the text is trimmed, 
  Without the br tags the text would be in a single line and dot's would be displayed
</div>
```

If CSS is not enough you can suggest solutions using javascript or if you prefer jQuery

Comment: You wan't to have ellipse effect with multi line text, is that right?

Comment: No just, at the end of the text

Comment: I would consider timing string to certain length and appending it with 3 dots in the end, rather then rely on css and having lots of comparability issues in the end. Or have another data source for "Intro text", but from my experience don't try to do it with, just append 3 dots to your trimmed string

Answer (score 0):

**1- Webkit line clamb can help you** Yes! browser support poor

```
overflow: hidden;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 3;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

For your someDiv

```
#somediv {
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
```

**2- Another Pure Css Solution**

```
<div class="block-with-text">
Lorem Ipsum, dizgi ve baskı endüstrisinde kullanılan mıgır metinlerdir. Lorem Ipsum, adı bilinmeyen bir matbaacının bir hurufat numune kitabı oluşturmak üzere bir yazı galerisini alarak karıştırdığı 1500'lerden beri endüstri standardı sahte metinler olarak kullanılmıştır. Beşyüz yıl boyunca varlığını sürdürmekle kalmamış, aynı zamanda pek değişmeden elektronik dizgiye de sıçramıştır. 1960'larda Lorem Ipsum pasajları da içeren Letraset yapraklarının yayınlanması ile ve yakın zamanda Aldus PageMaker gibi Lorem Ipsum sürümleri içeren masaüstü yayıncılık yazılımları ile popüler olmuştur.
</div>


.block-with-text {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative; 
  line-height: 1.2em;
  max-height: 3.6em; 
  text-align: justify;  
  margin-right: -1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  width:80%;
}

.block-with-text:before {
  content: '...';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.block-with-text:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  margin-top: 0.2em;
  background: white;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pz03jur2/

Comment: @Gerard I provide another solution you can also check here http://hackingui.com/front-end/a-pure-css-solution-for-multiline-text-truncation/

Comment: Some browsers might have different line heights, so that would look awful you could end up having half visible line
P.S
I would better refer to server side text trimming in words if it exceeds max length or do the same in js, as it's more reliable and feels more natural